# Lookup on array item property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given the data structure below, how do I perform a query that replaces the `product` property on each order with the actual entity.

I.e. This is what I want:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "products": [
      {
        "amount": 1,
        "product": {
          "_id": 1,
          "description": "product 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "amount": 1,
        "product": {
          "_id": 2,
          "description": "product 2"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "products": [
      {
        "amount": 1,
        "product": {
          "_id": 3,
          "description": "product 3"
        }
      },
      {
        "amount": 1,
        "product": {
          "_id": 4,
          "description": "product 4"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The database:

```
db={
  "orders": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "products": [
        {
          amount: 1,
          product: {
            _id: 1
          }
        },
        {
          amount: 1,
          product: {
            _id: 2
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "products": [
        {
          amount: 1,
          product: {
            _id: 3
          }
        },
        {
          amount: 1,
          product: {
            _id: 4
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "products": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "description": "product 1"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "description": "product 2"
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "description": "product 3"
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "description": "product 4"
    },
    
  ]
}
```

Current failing attempt: https://mongoplayground.net/p/VgXBabVd7lQ

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$products"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "products",
      localField: "products.product._id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "products.product"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$products.product"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      products: {
        $push: "$products"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

For playground, see https://mongoplayground.net/p/U7Q-wTo4Oy7